# Mac OS SED replace '|' with '_" in filename

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to remove one or more pipe '|' characters from a file name and replace them with "_".   I have tried multiple variations using Mas OS SED.  But still I am getting errors.

So if have a filename like  "ABC | DEF |  GHI"

and I want to result filename to be "ABC_DEF_GHI"
how do I achieve this with SED
ie. remove blanks and replace pipe '|' with '_"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to rename a file or modify a list of file names stored in a file or modify a file name saved in a shell variable or something else? [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I am capturing the filename as a script variable and want to replace that script variable with a "cleaned" filename.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to use plain bash. If `$name` contains the file name, then `${name//|/_}` replaces `|` with `_`, so that you could do something like:

```
mv -i -- "$name" "${name//|/_}"
```